# Turtlesim doubt

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ros-humble

How to stop my turtle at specified coordinates in turtlesim. i used a python script in which i made a turtle move in specified manner. then i spawned another turtle and made in move in the same coordinates. now i cannot stop it even after trying many ways. [image: I used this code for turtle2]
If i un-comment the line, the turtle stops after going 1/4th way, and when its commented, it repeatedly goes in circle. i want it to stop after making the shape.

Comment: please do not post pictures of text ... post the text instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wanting to stop based on a position, but you're sending velocity commands with no mechanism for recording time. If you could record the elapsed time, you could implement a [dead reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning) method that would let you estimate your position by accumulating position deltas, where each position delta is the previous speed multiplied by the elapsed time.

If you have an angular velocity in radians per second, then you complete one revolution when you accumulate two*pi radians, or about 6.283 radians. If you monitor the time, you could do something like this:

```
currentRotation = 0
fullRotation = 6.283 # radians
pastTime = rospy.get_time()

while currentRotation < fullRotation:
    
    # Get the elapsed time
    currentTime = rospy.get_time()
    timeDelta = currentTime - pastTime
    pastTime = currentTime

    # Publish velocities
    vel = Twist()
    vel.linear.x = 2.0
    vel.angular.z = -1.5 # radians
    velocity_publisher.publish(vel)
    
    # Dead reckoning - numerically integrate the angular velocity
    currentRotation += abs(vel.angular.z) * timeDelta

# Cleanup - once you are done rotating, stop moving
vel = Twist()
velocity_publisher.publish(vel)
```

If you want to get more accurate, you'll need to use a position sensor.

Comment: It solved the problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: @AyushSingh please mark the answer as "solving your question"